# Absolute positioning child and parent height is 0

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

It is a common question, but I still have not found any solution for my issue.

The `.parent` is a slider and the `.child` are images.
I need pass `.child` height (which is an absolute-positioned element) to `.parent`.

`.parent` has `0px` height. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="parent">
   <img class="child"></div> 
</div>

.child {
  position: absolute; //It must be absolute , because slider works with this
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know the image dimensions or aspect ratio?

Comment: could you not add another `<img>` that's `relative` but with no `visibility`? This will make the hidden image take up space.

Comment: Javascript. But it would be more normal to set a height on the slider and let the children adapt accordingly...not the other way round.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes of course, image should be responsive

Comment: @Chris Where i should put it ?

Comment: @AroTonoyan what are the dimensions or aspect ratio of the image(s)?

Comment: @MichaelCoker 1919x765 , top:0 , left:0 , right:0

Comment: @AroTonoyan thanks, added an answer.

Comment: @AroTonoyan, not sure if my answer is useful here, but did you try it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you could perhaps add **two** `<img>` elements. One with `position: absolute` - as your application requires, and another one with `visibility: hidden` but with `position: relative`.

If you don't want to mess about with the markup, you could do something similar with pseudo-elements, such as `:after` or `:before`. But the idea is the same.

The parent now takes up the full height of your image. This solution may or may not work depending on your application, which isn't very clear in your question, but perhaps it's worth a try.

```css
.parent {
  background: #AAA;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
}

.child-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child" src="http://www.extremekitcars.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Sports-Cars.png">
  <img class="child-hidden" src="http://www.extremekitcars.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Sports-Cars.png">
</div>
```

Comment: it works  :) I have done some modification in my case and done . Thanks men , you save my day !

Comment: Glad I could help! Would you like ne to post the alternative solution as well? It's a bit prettier..

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used your trick by adding another element but hidden and position relative. Now my parent has the height i need but the child element with position absolute is not broken!

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the image dimensions, you can divide the height by the width and get the aspect ratio. Then apply that as a vertical padding percentage to the parent and that will make the parent match the image dimensions responsively.

```css
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 39.86451277%; /* (765 / 1919) * 100 */
}
```

```html
<div>some content</div>

<div class="parent">
   <img class="child" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1919x765"> 
</div>

<div>more content</div>
```

Comment: Pretty nifty solution if the dimensions are known.

Answer (score 0):

**what could be the solution if the child  is not an image rather the child is a div with unknown(auto) height because it needs accomodate for dynamic content ?**